# Load database column data to ListBox in NidoFrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I am using Nido Framework to develop my ASP.NET Web Application.I want to load my database column data to ListBox(database table have 3 column,I want to load one column data to ListBox)

Comment: did you trying Googling?

Answer (score 1):

Calling GetAllGeneric will create the query to load all the records. Now since you only want selected columns you can issue a command like this..

```
       response.Result.Select(o => new { o.column1, o.column2 }) // only two fields
          .AsEnumerable() // to clients memory
          .Select(o => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(o.column1, o.column2))
          .ToList();
```

As you can see this is almost like the way you load data from Entity Framework. Only different with Nido is that it is more controlled and managed than issuing a command to EF in row format.